# Display a 3D Worldmap in the UI

Tags: unity-game-engine

My goal is to show the worldmap, a group of 3D Models, with lighting, shading and a Post-Processing Effect inside the UI whenever the player wants to warp to a location.

The setup I came up with was that the worldmap is located in a different scene, this scene is loaded when the game is started, but the scene's main camera renders to a RenderTexture, which will then be displayed with a RawImage on the UI of the main scene.

The problem with this is that the worldmap scene then also uses the lighting of the main scene. Additionally, the RawImage seems a bit distorted, even though the resolution is set to 1920x1080, which is the same as the game window.

Is there a way to achieve my goal in another, easier way? It seems a bit 'hacky' the way I am currently doing it.

Comment: Whats the differences between the 2 scenes?

Comment: @Eddge Well, the _main_ scene is where all the gameplay takes place, the second scene is meant to contain only the worldmap. Apart from that they also use different lighting settings.